# Google Prediction API error "The project entered is invalid - it should be the numeric Project Number from Google APIs Console"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-prediction

My script have been working on triggers for many months. But last days error reports containing this error are sent to me. Script was not changed for sure, but project is shared between team members. Project ID used in script is valid for sure, project exists. So can anyone tell me what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found out that Google have changed parameters order days ago. Here are details http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/11/code-updates-required-for-apps-script.html
So optionalArgs parameter became the 1st parameter of most of functions

Answer (score -1):

This error typically indicates that the project you specified is not numeric.  Are you using the numeric "Project Number" from https://cloud.google.com/console#/project?